# Rails url_for with nested resource id instead of object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to build a url inside a controller for a nested resource:

http://0.0.0.0:3000/account/1/address/new

I could do: new_account_address_path(@account) but I'm inside the controller that has the account id on the context (params[:id]) I don't want to load the object from the db just to build the url.

What would be the best way to extend the rails helpers to to this: new_account_address_path(params[:id]) and have the
http://0.0.0.0:3000/account/1/address/new ?

I also dont want to create a dummy instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to pass the route arguments as a hash:

```
new_account_address_path(:account_id => params[:account_id])
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, another problem I'm having is that i want to use url_for for the create action but this helper is not generate: create_account_address_path(:account => params[:account_id]) I think the reason is because the url is the same as the index action and only the verb (post) is different, so what would be the best way of generating the resource create url inside a action ?

Comment: I think you want to use the `account_address_path` helper.  Be sure to pass in the `account_id` as before.  I'd look at [this guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#binding-a-form-to-an-object) as well.